# Android - Listview with asynctask to load images - sometimes show images sometimes not

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I'm trying to apply asynctask to load images at listview items.

I'm also trying to compare two values in order to know if the view still need to load the image.

```
        @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
      holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
      picPath = cursor.getString(18);

        if(picPath == null || picPath.isEmpty()){

          holder.myImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }else{

          savingPath = picPath;

          AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> showImage = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){


                Bitmap b1;
                String syncPath;
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                    syncPath = savingPath;
                    b1 = setImageToImageView(syncPath);
                    return null;
                    }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


                if (syncPath.equalsIgnoreCase(picPath)){

                    holder.myImage.setTag(syncPath);
                    holder.myImage.setImageBitmap(b1);
                    holder.myImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }else{


                    }

                    }

}

}

};
showImage.execute();
```

By comparing those two - I want to know if there's still a need to load the view with the image.

```
if (syncPath.equalsIgnoreCase(picPath))
```

What I'm getting is that sometimes it loads the images, sometimes it's loading only a few, and it's always the same images.

So any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks for any kind of help

EDIT

This is the changes I've made (Still not working- makes the app crash)

```
                 if(holder != null && holder.bitImage != null) {

                 holder.myImage.setImageBitmap(holder.bitImage);
                 holder.myImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             }else{

             savingPath = picPath;

             AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> showImage = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

             Bitmap b1;
             String syncPath;

             @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                    syncPath = savingPath;
                    b1 = setImageToImageView(syncPath);
                    return null;
                }

             @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                    holder.myImage.setTag(syncPath);
                    holder.myImage.setImageBitmap(holder.bitImage);
                    holder.bitImage = b1;
                    holder.myImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }


            };
            showImage.execute();
```

Comment: Would you mind formatting that code a little to make it easier for us to read and follow? Shouldn't take but a minute or so...

Comment: I tried...a bit more readable i guess

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having synchronization issues since `savingPath` is shared among all the AsyncTasks. I'd recommend you to use some of the popular libraries for image loading:

- [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)
- [UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper)

Those are some of the most popular. They are pretty easy to use, besides they have caching built-in, so there is no need for you to check if the url is the same or not - the library would load the image from its cache if it is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see a need of your if(picPath == null || picPath.isEmpty()) condition , since if you have already downloaded the image , you can set the bit map to view holder to hold the bitmap object. Add one more field in holder as **Bitmap bitImage** and assign the b1.

change this ..

```
 if(picPath == null || picPath.isEmpty())
```

as ..

```
 if(holder != null && holder.bitImage != null)
 {
  // set bitmap
  holder.myImage.setImageBitmap(holder.bitImage)
 }
 else 
 {
   // load the image using async task and set it to holder.bitImage 
   // also set it to the image view
   holder.myimage.setImageBitmap(b1);  // lets assume b1 is your image bitmap
   holder.bitImage = b1;

}
```

Comment: I'm not downloading image, it's images that are at the public folder of the phone. picPath is the file path that i took from mine app DB. And what do you mean in your code with - bitImage  - what it stands for?

Comment: Add a variable Bitmap bitImage; in the holder class

Comment: I really don't understand what this code meant to do with what I trying to do. You say if   - holder != null && holder.bitImage != null - then I'm setting the holder to holder.bitImage - ok, why? what's next? i have the asynctask - the code is for loading images when the user is scrolling at the listview

Comment: if the bitmap is not in the holder , only then load using async task.

Comment: ok and then at the else you say to put the bitmap that i will get in the holder.bitImage - but holder.bitImage  is not sets anywhere to show picture at the holder.myImage.

Comment: see my answer in if condition .. holder.myImage.setImageBitmap(holder.bitImage)

Comment: Ok let's think about the first time loading of the listview - so it wouldn't get to the if, because holder.bitImage is null - so it will go to the else, run inside the else the async task and sets the bitmap to holder.bitImage - at this scenario there will be no picture shown- because holder.bitImage is not sets with holder.myImage

Comment: Well I've tried your suggestion - made the app crashe

Comment: see my updated answer. If you find any problem share the updated code.

Comment: I've posted the code that I've tried - makes the app crash

Comment: move the holder.bitImage = b1; above holder.myImage.setImageBitmap(holder.bitImage);

Comment: You have to show me the complete code or add the crash logs

Comment: I've managed to get the app not crashing. I do need  if(picPath == null || picPath.isEmpty()) - because in some listview items there aren't any pictures. But when i tried to use the code you suggest, it won't show all images when scrolling at the listview

Comment: Yes. You have to make sure you are updating the image view only if(picPath != null && !picPath.isEmpty())